# Can I use the value(numeric) in the edit box to set it as the position on a scroll bar? If yes, then how?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, controls

Suppose in a dialog based application, I have a scroll bar and an edit box to display the position of the scroll bar.

Now, I want to improvise and put a value in the edit box myself and as soon as I type it, the scroll bar scrolls to that position.

Comment: Set up an event handler on change notifications for the edit control, and scroll to the position whenever the contents change. Sometimes you just have to put two LEGO® pieces together.

Comment: In the OnChange() event handler for your edit box, restrict the input chars to 0-9. Parse the value in the edit box as an integer and send the scroll bar a message to scroll to that position.

Comment: @VijayVaradan: Don't roll your own. The edit control sports an `ES_NUMBER` [Edit Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e36b89f.aspx), so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @iinspectable thanks for the guidance.. I will try this and reply back..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can select edit control and go to property window and make **Number** as TRUE.
  By this user can only enter numeric value in editbox.
  [image]
- Use `SetLimitText();` function to limit the length of character in edit control.

  ```
  m_edit.SetLimitText(2); // this will accept value from 0 to 99
  ```
- Call `ON_EN_UPDATE` this function will call every time when edit Control value changes.

[image]

Inside this function you can get the value of edit control.

```
CString strTxt;
m_edit.GetWindowText(strTxt);
int nIndex = _ttoi(strTxt);  // you will get integer value here.
```

Use this integer value to set the position of scroll bar.

Comment: although i had already gone through with this problem, but u have provided a good alternate solution :)